# GenrateSchema from DLL in nhibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have one DLL of ASP.NET MVC and Nhibernate Project which is having some models and it's mapping.
in my project i take reference of that DLL. now i want that when i run project Nhibernate will GenrateSchema of the models which are present in DLL how i can do this?

Comment: You will have to write code to launch the appropriate methods. Can you be a bit more specific in what problems you have?

Comment: See: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#toolsetguide-s1-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your NHibernate configuration, you can create a new SchemaExport object and call Create on it

eg:

```
var cfg = BuildNHibernateConfiguration();
new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(true,true);
```